# Ho to use Ubuntu's tomcat8-user package with IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am working with Ubuntu and would like to develop tomcat applications with IntelliJ IDEA.

I installed tomcat8-user and created an instance:

```sh
sudo apt-get install tomcat8-user
tomcat8-instance-create /home/myhome/tomcat
```

However when I try to configure tomcat in IDEA I just get the message "The selected directory is not a valid Tomcat home":

[image: screenshot of error]

When I click "OK" nevertheless I get the error "Application server libraries not found":

[image: Error: Application server libraries not found]

What is the problem? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea seems to expect certain files in certain default locations which are different on the user instance. Unfortunately IDEA does not quite communicate which files these are and where they are searched. However by creating the following symbolic links you can fix the problem:

```sh
ln -s /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/bootstrap.jar /home/myhome/tomcat/bin/
ln -s /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/tomcat-juli.jar /home/myhome/tomcat/bin/
ln -s /usr/share/tomcat8/lib/  /home/myhome/tomcat/
```

Comment: In my case the missing one are from servlet-api:                                   
   ln -s /usr/share/tomcat-servlet-api-3.0/lib/jsp-api.jar                                
   ln -s /usr/share/tomcat-servlet-api-3.0/lib/servlet-api.jar

Answer (score 6):

I have also encountered the same problem when I try to configure tomcat in IDEA. I tried the previous answer method, but failed.Here's my way.

**The message "The selected directory is not a valid Tomcat home"**
Because IDEA can not access the files in the folder,one solution is using the **"chmod"** command change all of subdirectories' permissions.

**Go to the directory which you install the Tomcat:**

`cd /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.15`

**Using the command change the permissions.**

`sudo chmod 777 * -R`

Comment: On Gentoo, you have to install `dev-java/tomcat-servlet-api` and then `ln -s /usr/share/tomcat-servlet-api-4.0/lib/* /usr/share/tomcat-9/lib`. See also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-96976